# ExceptionHandler class not being recognized

Tags: java, spring, api, exception, error-handling

I can't seem to be able to make the following code work.

For some reason neither of the following advice is being thrown to the controller.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ApiExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {

        String mensagemUsuario = messageSource.getMessage("mensagem.invalida", null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
        String mensagemDesenvolvedor = ex.getCause().toString();

        List<Erro> erros = Arrays.asList(new Erro(mensagemUsuario, mensagemDesenvolvedor));
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, erros, headers, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
    }


    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {

        List<Erro> erros = criarListaDeErros(ex.getBindingResult());
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, erros, headers, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
    }

    private List<Erro> criarListaDeErros(BindingResult bindingResult) {
        List<Erro> erros = new ArrayList<>();

        for (FieldError fieldError : bindingResult.getFieldErrors()) {
            String mensagemUsuario = messageSource.getMessage(fieldError, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
            String mensagemDesenvolvedor = fieldError.toString();
            erros.add(new Erro(mensagemUsuario, mensagemDesenvolvedor));
        }

        return erros;
    }

    @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler({EmptyResultDataAccessException.class})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleEmptyResultDataAccessException(RuntimeException ex, WebRequest request){
        String mensagemUsuario = messageSource.getMessage("mensagem.invalida", null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
        String mensagemDesenvolvedor = ex.getCause().toString();
        List<Erro> erros = Arrays.asList(new Erro(mensagemUsuario, mensagemDesenvolvedor));

        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, erros, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, request);
    }

    @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler({DataIntegrityViolationException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleDataIntegrityViolationException(DataIntegrityViolationException ex, WebRequest webRequest) {
        String mensagemUsuario = messageSource.getMessage("mensagem.invalida", null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
        String mensagemDesenvolvedor = ex.getCause().toString();
        List<Erro> erros = Arrays.asList(new Erro(mensagemUsuario, mensagemDesenvolvedor));

        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, erros, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, webRequest);
    }

    public static class Erro {
        private String mensagemUsuario;
        private String mensagemDesenvolvedor;

        public Erro(String mensagemUsuario, String mensagemDesenvolvedor) {
            this.mensagemUsuario = mensagemUsuario;
            this.mensagemDesenvolvedor = mensagemDesenvolvedor;
        }
    } }
```

Project Structure :

[image: project struct]

It's my first time creating controller advice this way so would very much appreciate if someone could point me what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: I would like to see your package structure and exception actually you are trying to get into `@ControllerAdvice` class

Comment: @Deadpool just edited the post to include the project struct, see if that helps!

Comment: I guess you are not getting DataIntegrityViolationException in your controller. Don't catch the exceptions also you can check the Exception type in Controller.